# $wpdb not working in file of WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working in WordPress plugin. I create a custom form where user add values and then click on submit button. When user click on submit button its redirect to custom process file, where i write queries for inserting and updating data.

I my **process.php** file, first i call **global $wpdb**, but my insert and update queries not working so i found a solution from net to require **config.php** file in my process file.

```
require_once( str_replace('//', '/', dirname(__FILE__) . '/') . '../../../wp-config.php');
```

Then **global $wpdb** work perfectly. But the wordpress repository says that its illegal. I already include my form.php file in plugin main file **index.php**, so i also include **process.php** and comment the require_once code but its not working. I don't know how can i fixed this issue.

Here is my form.php code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>settings_process.php">

<input type="text" name="post_name_slug" id="post_name_slug" value="<?php echo POST_NAME_SLUG ?>" />

<input type="submit" name="save_settings" value="<?php _e("Save Changes","abc") ?>" />
```

And here is my process.php code:

```
require_once( str_replace('//', '/', dirname(__FILE__) . '/') . '../../../wp-config.php');
    global $wpdb;

My insert and update queries
```

So is there any other solution for this, please help me.

thanks alot

Comment: Are your trying to process the form data with ajax ? If so why dont you use the admin-ajax.php methode instead of including wp-config.php. There you can make use of $wpdb inside the wp_ajax_my_action action.

Its faster, cleaner and more secure. Still i dont know why its telling you that it is illegal. Did you check the  query directly ?

Comment: illegal means this is against the rules of WordPress .... no i don't use the ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using WP actions can solve your issue. Your problem is that you don't give WP chance to go through it's lifecycle and load all neccessary sources. Tweaking it by including config file is not a good way to go. You can register an action during plugin loading or `__construct()` function if the plugin is encapsulated in a class.
There are several actions you can use for this purpose, I'm mostly using these:

- wp_ajax_{action_name} - if using AJAX
- admin_post_{action_name} - if request is from logged user in wp-admin
- admin_post_nopriv_{action_name} - if anybody can do this request

The code is then simple:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mysettingsprocess', 'mySettingsProcess');
//If plugin "is object"
add_action('wp_ajax_mysettingsprocess', array($this, 'mySettingsProcess');
```

if this line of code is present in your plugin sources it will try to call `function mySettingsProcess() { ... }` function. Inside this function you will have no problem using `$wpdb` global var. You also have to provide a proper response for the request, WP will not do this for you.

Form actions will then look like this:

- for `admin_post_` and `admin_post_nopriv_`: http://{wp_url}/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=mysettingsprocess
- if using JS/JQuery and AJAX add to `data: { action: 'mysettingsprocess' },`

All these information are described in detail in  [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/). Generally I would use WP built in functionality to launch any plugin custom code. Adding PHP sources living outside WP is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanx alot bro for ur answer ... u save may 'week' ;)